# WP_User_Query not returning users with meta - what am I missing?

Tags: user-meta, wp-user-query

I think I'm missing a step here, but for the life of me I can't see it. I'm trying to display a simple list of users who all have the same role and have the same meta data value for a certain key - namely, teachers associated with a school.

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="teachers-list">
            <h3>Your School's Teachers</h3>
            <ul>
                <?php

                $champion_user = wp_get_current_user();
                $school = $champion_user->school;

                // echo $school just to test it's right.... ?> 
                Your school: <?php echo $school; ?>

                <?php 


                $args = array( 
                     'role' => 'subscriber',
                     'meta_key'    => 'school',
                     'meta_value'  => $school
                );

                // The Query
                $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

                // User Loop
                if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
                    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
                        echo '<li>' . $user->display_name . '</li>';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo '<li>No teachers found.</li>';
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

The school variable echoes properly, but then in the WP_User_Query I only get the "no teachers found" result. If I comment out the meta_key and meta_value fields, I get a list of subscribers, so that far works. If I manually code in the meta_value I'm looking for - in this case, "school_one", it still returns "no teachers found".  I checked the usermeta table in the db and all the users have the school meta key and the proper school values there, so... I'm stumped.

I've read and re-read the codex for both WP_User_Query() and get_user_meta(), and written this out both with the pre-WP 3.7 syntax and now the current syntax, but clearly I've missed the main point to get this working. Do I need to reset the query somehow? Do I need the "compare" argument too? Am I using the $school variable improperly in the arguments? I've tried so many methods I'm not sure what's left.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for reading.

Answer (score 1):

I finally sorted this out - there was a problem in the way that the db was storing the meta_value for my custom key. I had to repair the usermeta db table - I used a database checking plugin and then did the repair through phpMyadmin and now the query works properly.  Thank you to anyone who took a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Subscriber**, with capital **S**.

```
$args = array( 
    'role' => 'Subscriber',
    'meta_key'    => 'school',
    'meta_value'  => $school
);
```

:)

Comment: Thanks @mukto90 - unfortunately it doesn't change the output, still "no teachers found" and I know I've got 4 subscriber users on the site for dev purposes. Again, if I comment out the meta_key and meta_value lines, the code returns all these subscribers just fine, so it's something about that meta that's throwing me off.